# Gmaps4rails markers not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Having some trouble with markers not displaying with gmaps4rails, run through the tutorial video, still with no joy. I have confirmed that geocoder is working correctly.

@shops controller

```
def index
@shops = Shop.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@shops) do |shop, marker|
  marker.lat shop.latitude
  marker.lng shop.longitude
  marker.title shop.description
end
```

end

View

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
   <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
          markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
          handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
          handler.fitMapToBounds();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think `marker.title`might be the issue - have you tried `marker.infowindow`?

Also try: `handler.addMarkers(#{raw(@hash)})`

Sidenotes:
`@hash` is not a good name for a variable why not `@markers`?
Also I would call `.to_json` in the controller - I would leave that out of the view: just add `@hash.to_json` at the end of ```index``

I hope that helps!